# AWS secret key and Roles usage in the same aws s3 cp command

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

Assuming I'm on an EC2 instance which is configured with the destination bucket, is there a way to use keys for the source S3 bucket and do a copy something like this?

```
aws s3 cp s3://<Access key>:<secret key>@<source bucket folder> <destination bucket folder>
```

Answer (score 0):

The AWS CLI does not support specifying two different accounts to access buckets.

You do have options:

- Use the credentials for the destination bucket. In the account for the source bucket add a bucket policy granting your destination account read access to the bucket. [Details](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cross-account-access-s3/).
- If you cannot grant read access to the source account, create your own client using your favorite language and the AWS SDK. Initialize two client handles, one for each account. Then do a read/write copy operation. This is very easy to do in Python with boto3.